# printf doubles with fixed overall length

Tags: c, printf, double

I would like to printf doubles such that the overall length is always the same and the number is rounded if too long.

For example, with overall length 7:

```
double a = 1.23456789;
double b = 12.3456789;
double c = 123.456789;
printf("a: %f\n", a);
printf("b: %f\n", b);
printf("c: %f\n", c);
```

would print:

```
a: 1.23457
b: 12.3457
c: 123.457
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What if the integer part is exceeding the width? Like `123456789.12`

Comment: In my case, I have an if statement checking the size of the number. If it is too large or too small, I print it in scientific notation with `%e`

Comment: For the values shown, `%g` does the job — it even defaults to 6 significant digits as in your expected output.  Whether it will be adequate for you on larger ranges (`1.23456789E+34`, `-9.87654321E-34` is a different matter.  Don't forget to experiment with extremes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. See the [specifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for `printf` conversion specifiers. Use a `#` to select the *alternative form* to keep the trailing zeros. Use the `g` to obtain a representation with a fixed total number of digits. The `.6` specifies the exact number of digits.

```
printf("a: %#.6g\n", a);
printf("b: %#.6g\n", b);
printf("c: %#.6g\n", c);
```

A precision of 6 digits happens to be the default, so this works as well

```
printf("a: %#g\n", a);
```

Comment: no, 6 is the number of digits after the decimal point, not the total significant digits. Right from the above link: `Precision specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the decimal point character`

Comment: @phuclv: but trailing zeroes are omitted.  And the rules are somewhat more complex for `%g` — see the POSIX specification for [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html), which matches the C specification (C11 [`fprintf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)) in this area (and in most areas).

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("a: %.6g\nb: %.6g\nc: %.6g\n", a, b, c);
```

See [ideone](https://ideone.com/qKioRp)

Comment: The `.6` is the default, so for the data in the question, you can use just `%g` and get the same result.  But you also have the control available from specifying width and precision.

Comment: @pmg This is incorrect. The question is to print the numbers "such that the overall length is always the same" and this removes trailing zeros.